# Asp.net image control issue

Tags: c#, imageview

I have a problem with my image control that is when I upload an image it shows that image but when I update it, its shows old image while updates in database I think it gets image from cache is there any technique to handle this issue kindly tell me?

```
Image1.ImageUrl = populatedata.ResultSet.Tables[0].Rows[0][12].ToString();

            string file_ext = Path.GetFileName(Image1.ImageUrl);

            Image1.ImageUrl = "~/EmpImages/" + file_ext;
```

thanks

Comment: You'll probably need to provide some code in order to get a reply to that sort of question :)

Comment: We meant that you should include the code in your original question. Use the "edit" link under the tags to add it. Indent each line with 4 spaces to produce a code block with syntax highlighting.

Comment: any 1 willing to help me  please its too urgent

Comment: As Nathan said you have to include your code other wise it is hard to help

Answer (score 0):

Could you try adding a random querystring value on the end of the url? 
IE

```
string qs = DateTime.Now.ToString();

Image1.ImageUrl = string.Format("~/EmpImages/{0}?q={1}", file_ext, qs);
```

Wouldn't this cause it to make a new request for the image?

Comment: it shows old image in same browser but shows new image in new browser

Comment: there is no 1 to help meeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee

Comment: @Dave
my image is binded with a unique id so date time is not solving my problem what should i do?